# Weird behaviour with CCTexture2D (v simple code)

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

In my app I've got a CCTexture2D, which I'm creating using an image, creating a sprite from the texture, then adding to the stage, like this:

```
UIImage* faceUIImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"face.jpg"];
CCTexture2D* faceTest = [[CCTexture2D alloc] initWithImage:faceUIImage];
CCSprite* testSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:faceTest];
[self addChild:testSprite];
testSprite.position = CGPointMake(200, 100);
```

(I know this might seem a weird way to do it, but I'm doing some stuff to the pixel data elsewhere in the program, so I cant just use a pure sprite).

In the simulator, it looks fine:

[image]

However, when I run it on my iPhone (running 4.2), I get this:

[image]

Ignoring the fact that they are different orientations, how come the image on my device is in the background, and really dark? Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks,
Rich

Answer (score 0):

Did you try :

```
[self addChild:testSprite z:1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I fixed this simply by changing the jpg to a png instead... Maybe cocos2d doesnt really like jpg?